# Compare data in two dataframe and isolate the result

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have two datasets, one with elements and their respective values (data frame: `All_data`), and another (data frame: `Standard`) where I have the standard for each ratio. **I would like to compare which of the components of `ALL_Data` has all the variable superior to the one in the `Standard`.**

```
> All_Data
   Ticker   ROA ROE ROI
1   A       0.0 2.0 3.0
2   B       5.0 3.8 7.0
3   C       1.0 0.0 2.0
4   D       3.0 1.0 5.0
5   E       4.0 4.0 6.0
6   F       2.0 5.0 4.0

> standard
    Label  Value
1   ROE     3.0  
2   ROA     3.5
3   ROIC    3.8
```

The result  should be "E" and "B". 
This seems easy but I have no idea how to code it
I would really appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: You have two `matrix` objects by the look of it. Notice how all your values have `""`'s. That means even your numbers are stored as text strings - I think you might want to reconsider how you have made your data in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the compared values into a vector `standard` which has the same order as the order of the columns of `All_Data` and then we can use `Map` and `Reduce` function to solve the problem:

```
sv = standard$Value[match(standard$Label, names(All_Data)[-1])]
sv
# [1] 3.5 3.0 3.8  # note here that the order will be ROA, ROE and ROI

All_Data$Ticker[Reduce('&', Map('>', All_Data[-1], sv))]
# [1] B E
# Levels: A B C D E F
```

A little bit break down, since you are comparing each column to a corresponding value in the standard data, you can use `Map` to loop through the columns and values simultaneously and do the comparison which will return a list of three logic vectors which say if each element is larger than the value and then use `Reduce` function to apply `&` on the three vectors to make sure every element in a row is larger than the corresponding value.

*Data*: (assuming here that `All_Data` has been converted to a data frame where the last three columns are of numeric class.)

```
dput(All_Data)
structure(list(Ticker = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), ROA = c(0, 5, 1, 3, 4, 2), 
    ROE = c(2, 3.8, 0, 1, 4, 5), ROI = c(3, 7, 2, 5, 6, 4)), .Names = c("Ticker", 
"ROA", "ROE", "ROI"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Hi Psidom, Thank you very much. Apologies as I created this example, in my real case there are more than 60 variables, and 20000 lines, and it is not a matrix but assume it is a dataframe actually. Would you have a solution to handle so much data ?

Comment: Just updated the answer. This should work for you, assuming your standard is a data frame already. I suggest you edit your question to reflect that your data is data frame so that It will not confuse others who have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sweep` with `rowSums`

```
m1 <- `dim<-`(as.numeric(All_Data[,standard[,"Label"]]), dim(All_Data[,-1]))

All_Data[,"Ticker"][!rowSums(!sweep( m1, 2, as.numeric(standard[,"Value"]), ">"))]
#[1] B E
```

NOTE: Here the data used is similar to the one in the OP's post with minimal assumptions except that "ROIC" is a typo of "ROI".

#### data

```
standard <- structure(c("ROE", "ROA", "ROI", "3.0", "3.5", "3.8"),
 .Dim = c(3L, 
 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Label", "Value")))

All_Data <- structure(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "0", "5", "1", "3", 
"4", "2", "2.0", "3.8", "0.0", "1.0", "4.0", "5.0", "3", "7", 
"2", "5", "6", "4"), .Dim = c(6L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
c("Ticker", "ROA", "ROE", "ROI")))
```